# how to use keyboard shortcut to add folder in atom?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

In [`Atom`](https://atom.io/), I can use keyboard shortcut `a` to add a file.

But how can i use keyboard shortcut to add a folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

focus on the tree-view and hit **shift+a** and upper panel will show up just like adding a file to the project.

if you want to see all the keys shortcut goto:
**Setting->Packages->Core Packages->tree-view->Keybinding list**

Comment: You can see this GitHub Repo for more shortcuts on how to work with tree view. Very helpful IMO.
https://github.com/atom/tree-view